# ERROR: Error installing capybara-webkit:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capybara, capybara-webkit

Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.11.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
sh: qmake: not found


Gem files will remain installed in /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capybara-webkit-0.11.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/capybara-webkit-0.11.0/./gem_make.out
```

Comment: What platform are you trying to install capybara-webkit on?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

If you are in Ubuntu do

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```

If you are on Mac

```
brew install qt
```

and then

```
gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.11.0'
```

Comment: I had to `export QMAKE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4` on RHEL6.

Comment: I already had qt installed and it was still failing. Make sure that you uninstall qt and reinstall it if this is the case for you. The latest version of Capybara should work on the latest version of Mavericks on Macs.

Comment: Worked for me on os x Yosemite

Comment: Similar issue, but since I used brew I needed to supply a path to where qt5 is installed.  
`export QMAKE=/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.1_1/bin/qmake`

Comment: For Mac see Waynn Lue's comment below

Comment: On alpine please use `apk search qt4` or `apk search qt5` and install whatever you need using `apk add [name without version]`

Comment: I had to `brew link qt --force`

Comment: In case of ubuntu, if you get an error `Unable to locate package` then run following command instead mentioned above:
`sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libqtwebkit-dev`
This will do the job.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04: `sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqt4-dev libqtwebkit-dev`

Answer (score 21):

For Ubuntu 16.04

`sudo apt-get install qt-sdk`

Followed by

`gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.11.0'`
or replace with whatever version you want to install.

Comment: Worked for me as well on Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 16):

You are probably missing the qt libraries. See the [capybara-webkit wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit) for instructions on installing them for your platform.

Answer (score 5):

`brew install qt` will only install (as of August 4, 2015) `4.8.6`, which gives you this message.

```
WARNING: The next major version of capybara-webkit will require at least version 5.0 of Qt. You're using version 4.8.6.
```

Instead, if you do

```
brew install qt5
brew link --force qt5
```

you won't get that error.

Answer (score 4):

On El Capitan or Yosemite, you may need to do
`brew install qt55`
according to the doc [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit).

Comment: Note that if you want to install version 5.5 specifically, you will now need to do `brew install homebrew/versions/qt55`.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 20.04 you can install qt5-default package

```
sudo apt-get install g++ qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
```

Then install the gem with the required version:

```
gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.11.0'
```

Comment: Still works in 2022!

Answer (score 0):

On fedora is a bit more complicated. I did the next which takes a while:

```
$ sudo dnf install make gcc-c++ gdb qt5*-devel qt-creator
$ export QMAKE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt5
$ gem install capybara-webkit
```

Then it worked!

[See more info on capybara-webkit wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#fedora-24-25)