# Unable to install capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, installation, rubygems, capybara-webkit

When I run

```
 abhay$ gem install capybara-webkit
```

I get the following error messages.

```
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb


  Gem files will remain installed in /Users/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/capybara-     webkit-0.12.1 for inspection.
  Results logged to /Users/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/./gem_make.out
```

Comment: Can you provide a backtrace? Better yet, paste the error message in its entirety in gist.github.com or pastie or any other similar service and link it here.

Comment: I just got it working. I had to install QT. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install QT [link](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Support_for_Mac_OS_X) as capybara-webkit gem uses it to compile and install.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622193

I found the solutions in this answer worked well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622193/3088748